# Como usar o input radio com input hidden

Tags: php, html

Estou querendo gravar dois campos de uma tabela simultaneamente, seria o campo "gale_fotos" e o "gale_status" e estou usando o código abaixo, porém ele somente grava o campo "gale_status" como Não.

Como faço para que ele grave no Campo "gale_status" o SIM, quando clicado na opção SIM.

```
    <div align="center" style=" padding:2px; border-right:solid 1px;float:left; width:210px; height:auto; float:left;">
    <?php
    include '../conexao.php';
    $codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
    $gale_fotos = $_POST['gale_fotos'];
    $gale_status = $_POST['gale_status'];

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu");
    $res = mysql_fetch_array($query);

    if(isset($_POST['gale'])){

    $gale_fotos = $_POST['gale_fotos'];
    $gale_status = $_POST['gale_status'];
    $update = mysql_query("UPDATE menu SET gale_fotos = '$gale_fotos', gale_status = '$gale_status'");

    if($update == ''){
    echo "<script language='javascript'>
    window.alert('Erro ao Habilitar Link Galeria de Fotos!');
    </script>";
    }else{
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL= menu_halitar_link.php'>
    <script language='javascript'>
    window.alert('Link Galeria de Fotos Habilitado com sucesso!');
    </script>";
    }}?>

    <form name="gale" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>Habilitar o Link Galeria de Fotos?</label><br /><br />

    <label>Sim</label>
    <input type='radio' name='gale_fotos' value='<li><a href="<?php echo $res['dominio'];?>galeria.php" class="nav1">Galeria de Fotos</a></li><li class="divider"></li>' />
    <input type='hidden' name='gale_status' value='Sim' /><br />

    <label>Não</label>
    <input type="radio" name="gale_fotos" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="gale_status" value="Não" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="gale" value="Atualizar" />
    </form>
    </div>
```

Desde já agradeço a atenção de todos.

Answer (score 0):

Com o evento `onclick` do javascript, atribua um **value** `(document.getElementById('campoOculto').value='valor')` para o input hidden (identificado por um ID específico) de acordo com o radio selecionado.

```
<label>Sim</label>
<input type='radio' name='gale_fotos' value='...'
onClick="document.getElementById('campoOculto').value='Sim'">
<label>Não</label>
<input type="radio" name="gale_fotos" value=''
onClick="document.getElementById('campoOculto').value='Não'"/>

<input id="campoOculto" type="hidden" name="gale_status" value="" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Eu fiz uma implementação hoje para checkbox, mas que também funciona para o que você precisa com radio, dá uma olhada:

**HTML:**

```
<input id="chkCamp1" name="rad" type="radio" data-check="1" value="elemento 1"> elemento 1
<input id="chkCamp2" name="rad" type="radio" data-check="2" value="elemento 2"> elemento 2
<input type="text" data-view>
<input type="hidden" data-hide>
```

**E o JavaScript:**

```
$(function() {
    $('[data-check]').on('click', function() {
        var myInput = {valor: $(this).val(), id: $(this).data('check')};
        $('[data-view]').val(myInput.valor);
        $('[data-hide]').val(myInput.valor);
    });
});
```

Ele funcionando:
**http://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/9wzsu3wt/5/**

Comment: Ivan, primeiro muito obrigado pela sua atenção ao meu problema. Mas eu tentei com a sua dica e não deu certo, ele continua pegando o Status Não quando seleciono o Sim. Eu consegui fazer com que ele pegue o status correto, mas só fazendo dois form, um para cada Input Radio e hidden, mas fica com dois botoes de atualizar.
Vou continuar tentando, conseguindo publico a solução. Mas se alguém  puder me dar uma ajuda ficarei agradecido.

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['gale'])){
$gale_fotos = $_POST['gale_fotos'];
$update = mysql_query("UPDATE menu SET gale_fotos = $gale_fotos'")or die(mysql_error());

if($gale_fotos != '<li><a href="<?php echo $res["dominio"];?>galeria.php" class="nav1">Galeria de Fotos</a></li><li class="divider"></li>'){
 $update = mysql_query("UPDATE menu SET gale_status = 'Sim'");
 }else{
 $update = mysql_query("UPDATE menu SET gale_status = 'Não'") ;
 }`

Eu fiz essa alteração, mas pega somente uma das opções. Ele não deveria fazer a comparação e gravar de acordo com essa comparação? Pô galera, por favor...HEELPP.....

Comment: Isso ocorre porque o value retornado do campo gale_status no PHP é sempre o do segundo input hidden do HTML. Experimente trocar os values dos inputs hidden e verás que sempre retornará SIM.